# Selecting elements in an array by property name

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating a function props(list, propertyName), where I am passing in an array (list), and a property name. I want to run through the indices, add the elements associated with the specific property name, and return the array. This is what my function:

```
function props(list, propertyName) {
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
    output.push(list[i][propertyName]);
  }
  return output;
}
```

For example: if

```
var testing = [{ a:3, b:‘Cat’, c:true }, 13, { a:12, b:‘Hat’, c:false }, { cat:3, hat:‘3’, rat:false } ];
```

and I call: 
props( testing, ‘b’ )
it should return:

```
[ ‘Cat’, undefined, ‘Hat’, undefined ]
```

Comment: what is the issue then?

Comment: You should use `.map()`.

Comment: Abd what does it return?

Comment: @JonasW. it returns the array named output

Comment: [So it does](http://jsbin.com/kefogubevi/edit?console) when you would use real javascript quotes: "